# Room and SQLite: Migration didn't properly handle Entity

Tags: android

I know there are a few posts on this question. But I cannot figure it out. I have an existing SQLite DB. I am trying to migrate this DB to Room. At runtime I am getting this error:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: offerings(test.db.OfferingEntity).
 Expected:
TableInfo{name='offerings', columns={date=Column{name='date', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, freewill=Column{name='freewill', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, offered=Column{name='offered', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, thanksgiving=Column{name='thanksgiving', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, heave=Column{name='heave', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, type=Column{name='type', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, experience=Column{name='experience', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, favorite=Column{name='favorite', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, verses=Column{name='verses', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, wave=Column{name='wave', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, vow=Column{name='vow', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
 Found:
TableInfo{name='offerings', columns={date=Column{name='date', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, freewill=Column{name='freewill', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, offered=Column{name='offered', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, thanksgiving=Column{name='thanksgiving', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, _id=Column{name='_id', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=1, defaultValue='null'}, heave=Column{name='heave', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, experience=Column{name='experience', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, type=Column{name='type', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, favorite=Column{name='favorite', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, verses=Column{name='verses', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, wave=Column{name='wave', type='TEXT', affinity='2', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}, vow=Column{name='vow', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, primaryKeyPosition=0, defaultValue='null'}}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[]}
```

The difference is in

```
freewill=Column{name='freewill', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=true, ...}
```

and

```
freewill=Column{name='freewill', type='INTEGER', affinity='3', notNull=false, ...}
```

Column `freewill` apparently requires `notNull=true`. Here is what I tried:

1) In my Entity, I used the `@NonNull` annotation:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = FREEWILL)
@NonNull
private int freewill = 0;
```

Here, the error message did not change: Same IllegalStateException occurs.

2) In the migration, I used:

```
database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + OfferingEntity.TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + OfferingEntity.FREEWILL + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0");
```

Here, I got the following error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: duplicate column name: freewill (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: ALTER TABLE offerings ADD COLUMN freewill INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Of course, this column exists already and my code adds the same column again. Thus the error.

This is my Database class:

```
@Database(entities = {OfferingEntity.class}, version = 6, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class OfferingsDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
private static OfferingsDatabase INSTANCE;

public static OfferingsDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if(INSTANCE == null) {
        synchronized (LOCK){
            INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), OfferingsDatabase.class, DbUtil.DB_NAME)
                    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_5_6)
                    .build();
        }
    }

    return INSTANCE;
}

public abstract OfferingsDao offeringsDao();

static final Migration MIGRATION_5_6 = new Migration(5, 6) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL("ALTER TABLE " + OfferingEntity.TABLE_NAME + " ADD COLUMN " + OfferingEntity.FREEWILL + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0");
    }
};
```

}

Here the Entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = OfferingEntity.TABLE_NAME)
public class OfferingEntity {
static final String TABLE_NAME = "offerings";
static final String ID = "_id";
static final String FREEWILL = "freewill";


@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
@ColumnInfo(name = ID)
private int id;


@ColumnInfo(name = FREEWILL)
@NonNull
private int freewill = 0;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


public int getFreewill() {
    return freewill;
}

public void setFreewill(@NonNull int freewill) {
    this.freewill = freewill;
}
}
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: please show your database class.

Comment: Added database class. Thanks for the note.

Comment: is the same w/o default?

Comment: sorry I asked about OfferingEntity

Comment: Added entity class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to change `int` to `Integer`. Then it worked as expected.